# In which location the created txt file will be stored in ios device

Tags: ios

I have created a log file sing the following code.

```
-(void)logme:(NSString *)mymessage
{
    NSString *content = mymessage;

    //Get the file path
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locationlog.txt"];

    //create file if it doesn't exist
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileName])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName contents:nil attributes:nil];

    //append text to file (you'll probably want to add a newline every write)
    NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:fileName];
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
    [file writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [file closeFile];
}
```

and called this log file like,

```
[self logme:myHTML];
```

But I not able find where this log file created on my ios device physically,Where it will be stored in ios device?

Comment: You can found the answer to your solution in this [url][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323194/logging-from-the-iphone-where-is-the-file?rq=1

Comment: It is very helpful.http://stackoverflow.com/a/12323485/1119440

Comment: If i remove device from MAC the log file not updates

Comment: Why the log file not updated when i eject device from MAC. Then again connect device and open Sandbox the log file not updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's within a separate sandbox directory: in

```
/var/mobile/Applications/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/Documents
```

Where `XXXX... etc` is an UUID, randomly generated when the app is installed to the device.

Unless your device is jailbroken, you can't access this directory.